# Excel Add-in is not working on Apple's silicon M1 processor machine

Tags: excel, office-addins, apple-m1, apple-silicon, rosetta

I have an Excel Add-in which is working fine on Apple intel processor but not working on Apple's silicon M1 processor. When enabling Add-in On M1 processor machine, Excel is not responding.

With the [Workaround](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-office-for-mac-with-rosetta-and-apple-silicon-18db14f2-4abc-4d93-96a4-72a01f6e9721)  provided by Microsoft support suggests goto  "Applications->Excel->Get info" and enable "Open with Rosetta" then Add-in is working. We can't ask each and every user to perform these steps manually.

Any solution for this issue?

Comment: Are you referring to users of organization-controlled devices? If so, why not run a system-wide change to force Excel emulation in Rosetta by default?

Comment: @Kat, That is the final step if we are not getting any solution to this case. for now we can't ask users to manually run their Excel with Rosetta. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though your Excel add-in is targeting the x86 architecture - this is why it works on a M1 when running under Rosetta 2.

The problem is that your version of Excel is natively supporting the M1 processor, hence it can't load the add-on. By choosing to follow the steps given my MS support, you're forcing Excel to run in an emulated x86 mode.

So, what to do about it?

Unfortunately there's not much to do, unless you're the author of the Excel add-on. If you are, I'd consider re-compiling it for M1 architecture Macs.

If it's a 3rd party add-on, I'd contact the 3rd party vendor, and have them update it for M1 compatibility.

Comment: 1. Yes. I am the author of this add-in.
2. **"I'd consider re-compiling it for M1 architecture Macs."**-- Do I need to do any specific changes to make it M1 architecture compatible? @Anders

Comment: I honestly don't know.... I'd assume that if you build the add-on on a M1-powered Mac, it'd just work for that architecture.